# Unable to blink LED on TM4C123G?

Tags: c, embedded, keil

My TI Tiva ARM program is not working on TM4C123G. Using board EK TM4C123GXL. Program doesn't blink on board RGB LEDs.  I am able to run other example program to check the LEDs, this program is from textbook TI TIVA ARM PROGRAMMING FOR EMBEDDED SYSTEMS. Need help to debug this program. Thanks

Code:

```
/*  p2.4.c: Toggling a single LED

/*  This program turns on the red LED and toggles the blue LED 0.5 sec on and 0.5 sec off. */

#include "TM4C123GH6PM.h"

void delayMs(int n);

int main(void)
{

    /* enable clock to GPIOF at clock gating control register */
    SYSCTL->RCGCGPIO |= 0x20;
    /* enable the GPIO pins for the LED (PF3, 2 1) as output */
    GPIOF->DIR = 0x0E;
    /* enable the GPIO pins for digital function */
    GPIOF->DEN = 0x0E;
    /* turn on red LED only and leave it on */
    GPIOF->DATA = 0x02;
    
    while(1)
    {      
        GPIOF->DATA |= 4;    /* turn on blue LED */
        delayMs(500);

        GPIOF->DATA &= ~4;   /* turn off blue LED */
        delayMs(500); 
    }
}

/* delay n milliseconds (16 MHz CPU clock) */
void delayMs(int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < 3180; j++)
        {}  /* do nothing for 1 ms */
}
```

I am using KEIL IDE-Version: µVision V5.36.0.0

```
Tool Version Numbers:
Toolchain:        MDK-Lite  Version: 5.36.0.0
Toolchain Path:    G:\Keil_v5\ARM\ARMCLANG\Bin
C Compiler:         ArmClang.exe        V6.16
Assembler:          Armasm.exe        V6.16
Linker/Locator:     ArmLink.exe        V6.16
Library Manager:    ArmAr.exe        V6.16
Hex Converter:      FromElf.exe        V6.16
CPU DLL:               SARMCM3.DLL          V5.36.0.0
Dialog DLL:         TCM.DLL              V1.53.0.0
Target DLL:             lmidk-agdi.dll       V???
Dialog DLL:         TCM.DLL              V1.53.0.0
```

Comment: What about if you 10x increase the delay count in the `delayMs()` function? I'm not familiar with the specs of TM4C123G but `3180` looks too small.

Comment: I think you should take a look at Pad control registers of GPIO once. Also you need to make sure whether to enable internal pull up of the particular GPIO Pin or not.

Comment: If you're compiling with code optimizations enabled, the compiler might remove all what `delayMs` is doing (as it's nothing). You could attempt a quick fix by prepending `volatile` to `int i, j;`, but then may also need to adjust the `3180`. First confirm that you can control the LED on/off, moving the code from the while loop before it, and having the loop empty.

Comment: _"not working"_ is unhelpful.  Does the red LED light?  Does the blue LED light but not blink or does it not light at all?  What compiler options have you applied?  Did you apply optimisation?  "_loading fine_" is unhelpful - how do you know this program is not "loading"?  More likely that it is running but not as you expected.  What did these other examples do?  Are they relevant?

Comment: It would be helpful for you to specify the board rather then just the MCU.  Or if it is a custom board (or the LED is not on the board) you should describe the hardware w.r.t. the LED drive.  I presume you are using https://www.ti.com/tool/EK-TM4C123GXL and referring to the RGB LED?

Comment: yes, using EK TM4C123GXL and ref. to RGB LED. this program is not running on the board, and need help to debug, its from text book TI TIVA ARM PROGRAMMING FOR EMBEDDED SYSTEMS.

Comment: Program is available on website as well , links 
http://www.microdigitaled.com/ARM/TI_ARM/Code/Ver1/Chapter2/Program2_4.txt

Comment: Your board has an _On-board In-Circuit Debug Interface_ you can debug it through that.  But to debug code you would normally want to switch optimisation off - and your problem will go away - as explained in article linked in my answer.  You do not appear be reading the answers or comments or addressing the questions in the comments - they are there to better understand your problem.  Most often a question in a comment should be answered by editing the question to add the missing information - not (only) by responding in a comment - SO is not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like some issue with the compiler version optimization. Reverted back to v5.
[image]

Comment: Works with the same compiler but the optimization set to -O0 https://imgur.com/a/60KbBtE

Comment: Yes, that was stated in an answer already given (and several comments).  While you can answer your own question, if someone has already given that answer there is no reason to do so.  Either way you should accept an answer. - even if it is your own.  The use of the `volatile` keyword will prevent exactly that kind of optimisation.  Changing compiler or switching off optimisation is  an inappropriate solution.  You might read and understand the answers given.  If you do not understand or the solutions are not working for you, add a comment.

Comment: You should also address the comments against the question - they are there to improve your question and the subsequent answers.  This answer is in fact so horribly inappropriate I would advise deleting; it might attract down-votes.

Comment: to my observation, it doesnt matter if using keyword `volatile`, it just doesnt work if level 1 optimization flag is used. by default the optimization flag is set to 1 on compiler v6.

Answer (score 1):

If you must use a counting-loop delay, you must at least declare the control variables `volatile` to be sure they will not be [optimised away](https://www.embedded.com/introduction-to-the-volatile-keyword/):

```
volatile int i, j;
```

However it would be far better to avoid implementing delays that rely on instruction cycles and the compiler's code generation.  The Cortex-M core has a SYSTICK clock that provides accurate timing that does not rely on the compiler's code generation, changes to the system clock, or porting to different Cortex-M devices.

For example:

```
volatile uint32_t msTicks = 0 ;
  
void SysTick_Handler(void)  
{
    msTicks++; 
}

void delayMs( uint32_t n )
{
    uint32_t start = msTicks ;
    while( msTicks - start < n )
    {
        // wait
    }
}
  
int main (void)  
{
    // Init SYSTICK interrupt interval to 1ms
    SysTick_Config( SystemCoreClock / 1000 ) ;

    ...  
  
}
```

A busy-wait delay has limitations that make it unsuitable for all but the most trivial programs.  During the delay the processor is tied up-doing nothing useful.  Using the SYSTICK and `msTicks` defined as above you a better solution might be:

```
uint32_t blink_interval = 1000u ;
uint32_t next_toggle = msTicks + blink_interval ;

for(;;)
{
    // If time to toggle LED ...
    if( (int32_t)(msTicks - next_toggle) <= 0 )
    {
        // Toggle LED and advance toggle time
        GPIOF->DATA ^= 4 ; 
        next_toggle += blink_interval ;
    }

    // Do other work while blinking LED
    ...
        
}
```

Note also the use of the bitwise-XOR operator to toggle the LED.  That could be used to simplify you original loop:

```
while(1)
{      
    GPIOF->DATA ^= 4 ;
    delayMs( 500 ) ;
}
```