I'm studying embedded and I have a question about NOP()

I tried to blink STM32 Nucleo F103RB with register control the led connected to 8 pins. Just out of curiosity, I made the delay() function using the NOP() function.
Starting at 8 MHz, I thought it would amplify at PLL and run an internal clock of 64 MHz, so if I put a value of 64*(10^6) into my delay() function, I thought it would take about a second of delay. Sadly, however, my LED only turns off and on after a very long time. I noticed that my calculation was wrong that I couldn't of course time a second with an inaccurate clock, but at least it would blink similarly. I also tried to prevent compiler optimization with a bolatyle declaration. But seeing that there's no change, I'm sure there's a concept I'm getting wrong. What should I think to fix this? Please help me.
I'm not good at English. - Students who study in Korea -
....It is the same as the main content of the text.

Please don't post images of code, data or error messages.

NOP delays in ARM devices are generally unreliable (more or less, depending on a particular architecture and device). But more generally, your delay can't possibly work as intended on any architecture (even on those what allow for cycle-accurate instruction scheduling) because you are not accounting for time spent maintaining the loop itself. Counting down and looping would take at least 2 instructions; and each of them would take at least one cycle.

Your STM32 has a bunch of timers, which might be perfect for what you need. The Cortex-M CPU also has a sysTick timer, which can be configured to tick at whatever frequency you want. This can be used to implement accurate delays.

I would answer your question with the assembler that your source generates and demonstrate why volatile is required, even if in your observation it made no difference.  I might also have demonstrated a more reliable delay method.  However you posted a picture of your code, rather than the actual code, so I can't.  Not without manually transcribing your code that is.  It would have been a great answer that would have led to success and wealth in your embedded career ;-).   Still not too late to fix your question.

... some parts of that (volatile and a more appropriate delay method) are provided in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70514774/unable-to-blink-led-on-tm4c123g/70522196#70522196

A delay of a second most certainly calls for using a timer.

number one, you appear to be successful, and a count loop like this is the first thing you want to do with an mcu.  there is actually a long list and a whole books worth of issues that can make the execution/time performance of this loop vary.    Next time start with a number like 0x100000 and then double or half depending on what you visually see...Can use this to play with the pll and see the same count change the blink time but better is to next now use a timer with polling, not interrupts, and blink but now read about the clock tree and reset defaults.

there are other issues with the specific code, but it works so run with it for now.  the rare stm32 that wants a delay between the enable and first access to the gpio, is actually hard to cause that problem and your code as written would not have an issue with this race condition, no delay is needed.

For starters, your MCU does not run at 64MHz. It always boots with the default internal HSI oscillator. Upon boot, you're running at 8MHz. You need to configure the clock manually to boost it to 64MHz. This involves configuring PLL in RCC, as well as Flash wait states. For the sake of doing one thing at a time, you may want to stick with 8MHz for now.
Next, the NOP. NOP is actually not guaranteed to take a cycle. In fact, ARM documentation explicitly recommends to NOT use NOP for a delay. The processor pipeline may choose to ignore NOP completely and go straight for the next instruction. ARM Compiler toolchain Assembler Reference Version 5.03:

NOP does nothing. If NOP is not implemented as a specific instruction
on your target architecture, the assembler treats it as a
pseudo-instruction and generates an alternative instruction that does
nothing, such as MOV r0, r0 (ARM) or MOV r8, r8 (Thumb).
NOP is not necessarily a time-consuming NOP. The processor might
remove it from the pipeline before it reaches the execution stage.

Combine this with the fact that you need to loop the iterator (x more instructions per loop), plus some cores may have parallelization capabilities (multiple parts of ALU used in parallel to execute two non-interlocked instructions at a time), and you basically have non-deterministic delay.
Use asm volatile("MOV R8, R8"); when you need a delay of a few cycles. For example, such a delay would actually be recommended between you activating GPIO port clock and writing something to GPIO port registers. It usually works the way you have it (no extra delays), but in reality there are ~1-2 clock cycles until the peripheral registers are actually ready to be used. It's recommended to have some delay after the peripheral has a clock provided for it. In practice you can just put some other initialization code between RCC clock enable and you actually using peripheral registers.
If you want a delay larger than a couple cycles, hardware timer is your best bet. There is a small overhead for entering the interrupt (on the order of 10 cycles, varies by hardware, software configuration, and even if another interrupt handler is already running).

Why would mov r8, r8 be any safer from getting pipelined or eliminated from the pipeline? I would guess that with register renaming this would just update the register name (from r8 to r8, so a NOP on that level) and get dropped from the pipeline at that point. If it doesn't happen now it could happen next year.

I didn't understand you when you talked about register renaming something-something, no idea what you were trying to say. From what I know, MOV R8 R8 will not be optimized at the pipeline stage (at runtime), while NOP may. If MOV R8, R8 can be dropped from the pipeline in a similar fashion to NOP, please, provide a source.

My point was that nothing says mov r8, r8 will not be optimized away. If you read what you pasted you see that on thumb the NOP pseudo-instruction becomes mov r8, r8 followed by NOP is not necessarily a time-consuming NOP. So I would say the specs say quite the opposite, they explicitly warn that it might. On high powered ARM cpu this would happen quite naturally if they use register renaming in their pipeline stage.

To me it seems like you misinterpreted the text. The way I understand is, MOV R0, R0 does not get optimized away (ever). The source I provided says that if you write NOP, the compiler (at compile time!) may replace a NOP with MOV R0, R0. There isn't a single word about MOV R0, R0 being dropped from the pipeline. It talks specifically about dropping NOP from the pipeline, and MOV R0, R0 is not a NOP. If I misunderstood things, please provide some source that explicitly states this.

No, the compiler never replaces a NOP. It's the assembler that does this. And it's not a replacement but on CPUs that do not have a NOP opcode the assembler emits an opcode that is harmless and basically is a NOP. Historically with the reference saying a NOP will be mov r8, r8 it frequently lead to later CPUs optimizing that special opcode to be more efficient. Like how xor eax, eax is optimized on x86 CPUs because that use case of zeroing the register is so wide spread.

One more point: If the cpu is freshly booting then instruction and data caches won't be setup either. Executing a NOP will take far more than one cycle in that case. On an original RaspberryPi running a delay loop with NOP with and without caches enabled makes a difference of factor 10 in speed and modern RPIs are worse. A delay of a specific time needs to use a timer.

Your remark about compiler vs assembler is irrelevant here, you're being unnecessarily pedantic. It's merely a compile-time vs run-time qualifier in this context. Regarding optimizing away ARM MOV R0, R0, I'm still waiting for the source. Please, share a link so I can read an official doc I could refer to when talking about this, for now it's a "trust me bro" argument. You may be right, but I want to read a proper doc.

There is no official doc that says mov r0, r0 is being optimized out that I'm aware of. There is also no official doc that says 'mov r0, r0' or 'mov r8, r8' won't be optimized out. The official wording you pasted is: NOP is not necessarily a time-consuming NOP. and that realy is all there is. Weather the assembler generates a nop, mov r0, r0 or mov r8, r8 is irrelevant. You can't assume any of those will be time-consuming. And if you read my reasoning in previous comments it's quite likely not to be time consuming.

Well, there are clearly two ways to interpet the same text. My interpretation is that NOP instruction, if it is supported by hardware, can be dropped from the pipeline at run-time. Since at runtime MOV is not NOP, MOV will not be dropped from the pipeline. Then there is your way of interpreting it. NOP or any nothing-doing instruction replacing NOP can be dropped from the pipeline. Which is also a valid way to interpret the same text, admittedly. I admit, you sound confident, and I'm inclined to believe you, but I would want some kind of proof. At least an experimental one.

Someone had a similar question and conducted an experiment. I'm trying to interpret it: https://www.pabigot.com/arm-cortex-m/the-effect-of-the-arm-cortex-m-nop-instruction/

Delay using NOP is not suitable for anything but very short delays. With loops, the loop overhead is (very) significant compared to the NOP instruction itself which makes the behavior unpredictable.
In this case, you could use the STM HAL delay function or implement something similar.

You can use arm's timestamp counter register. This is CNTVCT_EL0.
You may also use the frequency register CNTFRQ_EL0 but I think that this needs to be set in S/W.
Here is some sample code:
#define RDTSC(_ctr) \
    __asm__ __volatile__("isb ; mrs %0,CNTVCT_EL0" : =r(_ctr))

void
tscdelay(uint64_t delay)
{
    uint64_t tscbeg;
    uint64_t tscnow;

    RDTSC(tscbeg);

    while (1) {
        RDTSC(tscnow);
        if ((tscnow - tscbeg) >= delay)
            break;
    }
}

You'll have to play with the value passed to tscdelay to match the actual frequency of your system. Since the system starts at 8Mhz and you adjust to 64Mhz, you already know how to scale the values.

Cortex-M3? Are you sure?
